# batch file scripting - Windows 7 Non-Volume License Activation

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

I'm trying to create a batch file for Activating Windows after cloning for individual pc license (not *Volume License*) but it seems not working. This will help a lot for tech support to speed up the process. Can someone help me figure out the problem please? My script below:

```
@ECHO OFF

pause

:WinActivation
SET WIN7Act=
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO ------------------------------------
ECHO - Activate Windows 7 Non-VL... -
ECHO ------------------------------------
slmgr.vbs -ipk SET /P WIN7Act=Input PRODUCT KEY and press [ENTER] (X to exit):
IF NOT DEFINED WIN7Act GOTO WinActivation
CALL :TR %WIN7Act% WIN7Act

:END
IF /I "%WIN7Act%"=="X" GOTO ENDED

:ENDED
EXIT /B

:TR
SET %2=%1
GOTO ACT

:ACT
slmgr.vbs -ato
echo.
echo.
echo.
GOTO ENDED
```

I would really appreciate for any help and advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few issues in your batch file. The following should have the flow I think you're after but you'll need to check the handling of `slmgr.vbs` and its parameters.

```
@ECHO OFF

pause

:WinActivation
SET WIN7Act=
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO ------------------------------------
ECHO - Activate Windows 7 Non-VL... -
ECHO ------------------------------------

SET /P WIN7Act=Input PRODUCT KEY and press [ENTER] (X to exit):
IF "%WIN7Act%" == "" GOTO WinActivation

IF /I "%WIN7Act%"=="X" EXIT /B

slmgr.vbs -ipk %WIN7Act% -ato
echo.
echo.
echo.
```

Comment: Sir @FloatingKiwi,

Thank you for your response. It seems that you answered my question so easily, you just have saved my day! I'm not quite yet familiar the handling of slmgr.vbs and thanks a lot for your advice.